# Why is AngularJS include not working in this simple example?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the content of main page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div ng-include="'goodbye.html'" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is the content of goodbye.html :

```
<h1>Goodbye</h1>
```

---

It just shows the "Hello" and doesn't add the "Goodbye" to that. Why doesn't it include the goodbye.html?

Comment: You don't actually bootstrap angular in your example. What does your JavaScript code look like?

Comment: @PankajParkar check it now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `ng-app` to bootstrap AngularJS.

Also, ng-include evaluate the expression passed so you need to pass a string `'goodbye.html'`, not `goodbye.html`

```
<html ng-app="example">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('example',[]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div ng-include="'goodbye.html'"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear , you just places your ng-app directive before you even load the angular into your page ... no that doesn't work ...

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, but because I do not initialize `example` module and ng-include evaluate the expression passed so you need to pass a string `'goodbye.html'`, not `goodbye.html`.

I edited my answer.

Comment: it worked , thanks , but doesn't it sound gotcha or redundant to  have that initiation script , It could be way cleaner without that ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `''` in the `ng-include`

```
<div ng-include="'goodbye.html'" ></div>
```

From the [**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

> Angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string
>   constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g.
>   src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Comment: see the structure of your files. Are they in the same level?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your html it seems that your application is not bootstraping automatically. It may be you are bootstraping your application manually. An other thing what I noticed is the ng-include takes path of your include html as string like..

```
<div ng-include="'goodbye.html'" ></div>
```